# A property of the derivatives of a function

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose that $f,g_1,g_2,\dots$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'=f\,g_1$ and $g'_j=g_j^2-g_j g_{j+1}$. Here and in what follows, $j$ is any natural number. Then, by induction, $f^{(j)}=f\, P_j(g_1,\dots,g_j)$, where 
$$P_j(u_1,\dots,u_j)=\sum_{k_1=0}^j\cdots\sum_{k_j=0}^j c_{k_1,\dots,k_j}
u_1^{k_1}\cdots u_j^{k_j}
$$
is a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[u_1,\dots,u_j]$ of degree $j$.

The problem is to show that 
$$\sum_{k_1=0}^j\cdots\sum_{k_j=0}^j |c_{k_1,\dots,k_j}|\, 
1^{k_1}2^{k_2}\cdots j^{k_j}=2^{j - 1} j! 
$$
for all natural $j$. 
This equality has been verified for $j=1,\dots,10$.

Comment: Out of curiousity, could you add some background about where this problem arose?

Comment: Steven: $f$ is actually the inverse Mills' ratio, $\varphi/\gamma_0$, and $g_j=\gamma_j/\gamma_{j-1}$, where $\gamma_j(t):=\int_t^\infty(u-t)^j\varphi(u)\,du$ and $\varphi$ is the standard normal density function.

Comment: Is the task to show that this identity holds for $j=1,\ldots,10$, or that is the part that you know already, and wish to establish the case for arbitrary $j$? (most likely you mean the latter, but just in case...) --- looks like some kind of Faa di Bruno....

Comment: Suvrit: The problem is to prove the identity for all natural $j$. It was checked for $j=1,\dots,10$. I have edited the question to clarify this. Faa di Bruno may not be directly applicable here, because the absolute values of the coefficients are taken, and then anyway the problem is to show that the di Bruno-like expression converts to the very simple one, $2^{j-1}j!$.

Comment: Do the signs of the coefficients appear to have a simple pattern?

Comment: Brendan: I haven't noticed any sign patterns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have, writing for short $P_n=P_n(g_1,\dots,g_{n })$,

$$\big(f^{(n)}\big)' =\big(fP_{n }\big)'=f' P_{n }+\sum_{i=1}^n f\partial_iP_ng_i'=fg_1 P_{n }+\sum_{i=1}^n f\partial_iP_n(g_i^2-g_ig_{i+1})$$
Comparing with $f^{(n+1)}=fP_{n+1}$ we obtain a linear recursion for the sequence of polynomials $P_n=P_n(x_1,\dots,x_{n })$
\begin{cases} P_1=x_1  \\ P_{n+1}=x_1P_n  +\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i+1}) x_i\partial_i P_n, \end{cases} 
whence it is clear that $P_n$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$, $P_ n:=\sum_{|\alpha|=n} c(\alpha)x^\alpha$, the sum being extended over all multi-indices $\alpha:=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots )$ of weight 
$|\alpha|:=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\dots=n.$

Equating the coefficients of the monomial $x^\alpha:=x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_{n+1}^{\alpha_{n+1}} $ of degree $n+1:=|\alpha|$ in the above recursive formulas  we obtain:
$$c(\alpha)= \alpha_1 c(\alpha-\delta_1)- \sum_{i=2}^{n} (\alpha_{i-1}-\alpha_{i }+1)c(\alpha-\delta_i) \; - \alpha_{n}c(\alpha-\delta_{n+1}),$$
where $\delta_i:=(\delta_{i1},\delta_{i2},\delta_{i3}\dots)$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is the usual Kronecker symbol.
From this formula for $c(\alpha)$ it follows easily by induction that

**(i)** If $c(\alpha)\neq0$ then $\alpha_1\ge\alpha_2\ge \dots  $;

**(ii)** $\operatorname{sgn}c(\alpha)=(-1)^{|\alpha|-\alpha_1}$.

As a consequence, the  sum we are interested in is  $$ \sum_{|\alpha|=n} \big|c(\alpha)\big|1^{\alpha_1}2^{\alpha_2}\dots n^{\alpha_n}=P_n( 1, - 2,- 3,\dots,- n).$$

To evaluate it, consider $\sigma_n(t):=P_n( t, - 2,- 3,\dots,- n).$ Then, by the recurrence relation of the polynomials $P_n$ 
and by the Euler formula for homogeneous polynomials we find
\begin{cases} \sigma_1=t \\ \sigma_{n+1} =(t+n)\sigma_n +  (t+t^2)\sigma_n' , \end{cases}

Now it is easy to check that
$$\sigma_n(t)=n!t(t+1)^{n-1},$$
whence $\sigma_n(1)=n!2^{n-1}.$

$$*$$

**rmk.** Also note that the polynomials $Q_n:=  \sum_{|\alpha|=n} \big|c(\alpha)\big|x^\alpha$ are simply $P_n(x_1, -x_2,-x_3,\dots,-x_n),$ whence one finds a linear recurrence relation for them

\begin{cases} Q_1=x_1  \\ Q_{n+1}=x_1Q_n+2x_1^2\partial_1Q_n  +\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i+1} - x_{i}) x_i\partial_i Q_n. \end{cases}

Comment: This is a great answer. I'd only suggest to make the dependence of $c(\alpha)$ on $n$ explicit: $P_ n:=\sum_{|\alpha|=n} c_n(\alpha)x^\alpha$, and then the recurrence for $c_n$ will be clearer (and better written "for $n$" rather than "for $n-1$", just as that for the $P_n$'s):  
$$c_{n+1}(\alpha)= \alpha_1 c_n(\alpha-\delta_1)- \sum_{i=2}^n (\alpha_{i-1}-\alpha_{i }+1)c_n(\alpha-\delta_i) \; - \alpha_nc_n(\alpha-\delta_{n+1}).$$ Also, I think it should be said that $\delta_i:=(\delta_{ij})_{j=1,2,\dots}$.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was thinking  the coefficients $c(\alpha)$ as a unique family indicized on the whole infinite set of multi-indices: since $P_n$ is homogeneous of degree $n$, its coefficients are those  $c(\alpha)$ with $|\alpha|=n$.

Comment: All right. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I also suspect there could be a closed formula for the $P_n$. For instance one can derive one variable recursions similar to that of $\sigma_n(t)$, along other characteristic lines.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. It seems one would then have to solve the system of ODEs $x_i'=x_i(x_i-x_{i+1})$ with $i=1,\dots,n$. You very cleverly exploited the special property of the arguments $(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(t,-2,\dots,-n)$, for which $x_i(x_i-x_{i+1})$ is simply $-i$ if $i=2,\dots,n-1$. In general, I am afraid the best one could do is recover that $f$ is expressed as a version of the inverse Mills ratio, with about $n$ constants of integration additionally involved. Then, as discussed with Suvrit, one can use di Bruno's formula, but then how to convert it to a simple expression?

Comment: Yes, it seems difficult… at the moment I have no ideas :/

Comment: However there are  simple particular solutions of the ODE, so maybe other identities for special values of $P_n$ are available.

Comment: As an experiment: if $p_n(t):=P_n(t,1,1,\dots,1)$ then $p_1(t)=t$ and $p_{n+1}=tp_n + t(t-1)p_n'$, a sequence of polynomials whose coefficients appear listed in https://oeis.org/A090582

Comment: Thank you Pietro for more thoughts on this problem. I am not sure if special values of the arguments other than $(t,-2,-3,\dots,-n)$ could be of further help in my situation. If $f$ is indeed the inverse Mills ratio, then one can see that $g_j(t)<j/t$ for $t>0$, which is why I was interested in the value of $\sum_{|\alpha|=n}|c(\alpha)|x^\alpha$ at the specific $x=(1,2,\dots,n)$.